# Union of two linked list- C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Any assistance will be helpful. I have written a code to find the union of two linked list. However, I am getting an infinite loop at one section. I indicate it in the code. Please help me identify the error. Thanks.

```
//Finds the union of two linked lists. 
nodeType* unionLL(nodeType *&headA, nodeType *&headB)
{
      nodeType *tempA, *tempB, *newNode;         
      tempA = headA;
      tempB = headB;
      bool match = false;

      while (tempB -> link != NULL)
      {
            while (tempA -> link != NULL)                
            {
                  outfile <<"The infinite loop occurs here " << endl;
                  if (tempB -> intVal == tempA -> intVal)
                  {   
                      match = true;
                  }  
                  tempA = tempA -> link;
            }

            if (!match)
            {
               newNode = new nodeType;
               newNode -> intVal = tempB -> intVal;
               newNode -> link = NULL;
               tempA -> link = newNode;
            }
            tempA = headB;
            tempB = tempB -> link;
      }

      return headB;
 }
```

Comment: How about just putting them into an std::set?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Comment: the '`->`' operator binds very tightly logically; don't write code with spaces on either side of it...it looks weird to experienced programmers.

Comment: Also, learn to declare and initialize your variables at the same time.  The declaration of `newNode` should be in the `if (!match)` block, only (and should be `nodeType *newNode = new nodeType;`).  You should also be using: `nodeType *tempA = headA;` and `nodeType *tempB = headB;` rather than declaring on one line and initializing later.

Comment: I don't think this is causing your infinite loop, but I am pretty sure 3rd to last line (tempA = headB;) is wrong and will cause this function to not work as intended.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler good or bad, I have seen code standards that require *all* variables to be declared at the top of the function.

Comment: @SoapBox: don't make me get on my soap box!  Any C++ coding standard that requires 'all variables at the top of the function' is a disaster.  It is archaic in a C coding standard - it was ante-pre-diluvian to require it in C++.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't disagree.  Any C++ standard like that is most likely a bad adaptation of an *old* C standard from the 90s.

Comment: SoapBox's observation is correct: `tempA = headB`, and from then on with each iteration through the big loop `tempB` advances one step in `B` and `tempA` appends another new node to `B`.

Answer (score 4):

You have not identified whether the linked lists are sorted or not - so we should assume not.  You have not identified which list can be modified; superficially, both lists could be modified by the function.  You return `headB` which suggests that the result should be that the result set accessible from `headB` should contain every element in that list, plus a new element for each element accessible from `headA` that is not already found via `headB`.

Superficially, then, your pseudo-code should be:

```
foreach element in listA
    if (element not found in listB)
        add copy of element to listB
```

leaving listA untouched.  Your code does not implement this logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll work on my code again and restructure it using the pseudo-code you gave me. This is really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not checking if it matches in tempA loop (neither in B's)